# Help with Morse Code Java assignment!

Tags: java

The value for the Morse Code translation keeps returning `null` and I've done everything I can think of to fix it.  We are restricted to using arrays on this assignment.  What can I do to correct it?

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class morseCodeTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException
    {
        String userInput;
        final String SENTINEL = "0";//for exiting program when entered

        //object creation
        Translate text = new Translate();

        //getting user input to be translated
        do
        {
            userInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter what you wish to translte to Morse code (no punctuation).");
            String compare = userInput.toUpperCase();
            String[] codedText = new String[compare.length()];

            codedText = text.translateHere(compare);
            text.toString(userInput, codedText);
        }while(!userInput.equals(SENTINEL));
    }//end main
}//end class

class Translate
{
    public Translate()
    {
    }//end default constructor

    public String[] translateHere(String s)throws IOException
    {
        String compare = s, codedLine = "";  //userInput toUpperCase
        int length = compare.length();  //length of userInput
        String line, file = "Morse.txt";// variable holding file name and variable for each letter/number
        char code;

        //Constants
        final int MAX = 36;

        //Arrays
        char[] morseLetter = new char[MAX];
        String[] morseCode = new String[MAX];
        String[] newMessage = new String[length];

        //putting user input in a character array;
        char[] userLetters = compare.toCharArray();

        //object creation
        File openFile = new File(file);
        Scanner inFile = new Scanner(openFile);

        //for loop that will read data from the Morse.txt file
        for(int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
        {
            while(inFile.hasNext())
            {
                line = inFile.next();
                code = (char)line.charAt(0);
                morseLetter[i] = code;
                morseCode[i] = inFile.next();
            }//end nested while loop
        }//end for loop

        for(int j = 0; j < length; j++)
        {
            for(int k = 0; k < MAX; k++)
            {
                if(userLetters[j] == morseLetter[k])
                {
                    newMessage[j] = morseCode[k];
                }
            }//end nested for loop
        }//end for loop
        return newMessage;
    }//end method that completes translateion

    public String toString(String a, String[] b)
    {
        String input = a;
        String[] coded = b;
        String[] encoded = new String[input.length()];
        //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Original Text: " + input + "\nCoded Text: " + coded);    
        for(int l = 0; l <input.length(); l++)
        {
            encoded[l] = coded[l];
        }   
        String str = "";
        System.out.print(Arrays.toString(encoded));
        return str;
    }//end toString method
}//end Translate Class
```

The Morse code text file contains the following:

```
1 .----

2 ..---

3 ...--

4 ....-

5 .....

6 -....

7 --...

8 ---..

9 ----.

0 -----

A .-

B -...

C -.-.

D -..

E .

F ..-.

G --.

H ....

I ..

J .---

K -.-

L .-..

M --

N -.

O ---

P .--.

Q --.-

R .-.

S ...

T -

U ..-

V ...-

W .--

X -..-

Y -.--

Z --..
```

Comment: What should your toString message actually do? your just shuffling strings from one array into another.

Comment: my toString method should print out the original message plus the morse code version of it and thats where I'm stuck.

Comment: After I add something like: 'String str;
  
  str = "original text: " + input + "\nmorse code: " + encoded;
  
  System.out.print(str);
'  it returns the memory address and I need the values

Answer (score 2):

Your `Translate.toString` method will always return an empty string because that's the only thing you assign to the `str` variable.

Comment: So how would I go about actually printing out the translated text stored in the array newMessage[] ?

Comment: I would loop through the array and build a string like in Roflcoptr's answer.  I would print the results in the calling method instead of in the "toString" method, though.

Answer (score 0):

```
public String toString(String a, String[] b)
{
   System.out.println("Input: " + a);
   System.out.println("Output:");

   String output = "";
   for(int i = 0; i < b.length; i++)
   {
      output = output + b[i];
   }

   return output;

 }//end toString method
```

But the real problem is this loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
        {
            while(inFile.hasNext())
            {
                line = inFile.next();
                code = (char)line.charAt(0);
                //System.out.println(code);
                morseLetter[i] = code;
                morseCode[i] = inFile.next();
            }//end nested while loop
        }//end for loop
```

There you try parsing the morse code letters into a file, but the problem is the for loop is in the first iteration and then, the whole while loop is executed, therefore you're always placing the morsecode in the first position of the array.

So it should look like that:

```
int  counter = 0;
        while(inFile.hasNext())
            {
                line = inFile.next();
                code = (char)line.charAt(0);
                //System.out.println(code);
                morseLetter[counter] = code;
                morseCode[counter] = inFile.next();
                counter++;
            }//end nested while loop
```

As an additional note: Did you noticed that if the user clicks cancel in your OptionsDialog that there is a NullPointer? Proper exception handling is part of the assignment I think ;)

Therefore I would write the loop like this:

```
do
        {
            userInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter what you wish to translte to Morse code (no punctuation).");
            if (userInput != null && !userInput.equals("")) {
                String compare = userInput.toUpperCase();
                String[] codedText = new String[compare.length()];

                codedText = text.translateHere(compare);
                text.toString(userInput, codedText);
            }
        }while(userInput != null && !userInput.equals(SENTINEL));
```

Comment: After changing my code to imitate this I get a blank space where output should be.  I also just tried using JOPtionPane and it appears that I just get the location of my array holding the Morse Code translation in memory.

Comment: oh yes there is a small error in the answer. I corrected it. sorry.

Comment: My output using that is as follows: [Ljava.lang.String;@4b222f[null]
Input: a
Output:       I appreciate the help by the way!  I know this might seem like a waste of time or something but I've been working on this for awhile now ><

Comment: I tested your programm an the problem is, your array that your'e passing to your toString method does only contains null.

Comment: Yeah I'm working on figuring that one out now but no luck yet

Comment: Yeah I had noticed that >< the display part was driving me nuts so I had been working on that!  But thank you for all the help!

Comment: Yes with my corrected version it is checked if the user presses cancel or if the input isn't there.